# Imprimir contenido etiquetas HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Hola soy nuevo en esto de python y estoy intentando imprimir el contenido de etiquetas que encuentro dentro de una cierta pagina web.

Os voy a poner mi caso:

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que pueda ver que dominios estan siendo hosteados dentro de un server.
Para esto estoy usando la pagina viewdns.info, la cual te dice que dominios estan hosteados en un server, por un reverse_ip.

Este es mi codigo

[image: codigo del programa]

como podeis observar hago  una peticion a la pagina, y el codigo lo meto en la variable b usando beautifulSoup, y dentro de este con la variable c buscamos la id "null", que es la que contiene los resultados. y despues buscamos "border=1" que esta dentro de la etiqueta null  y tambien contiene los resultados.

el problema es que al iniciar el codigo nos da un fallo Nontype ,porque no encuentra la etiqueta, pero si existe ya que la vi dentro del codigo fuente de la pagina:

[image: id null]

entonces lo que hice es imprimir b (Soup), ya que es el codigo que estoy analizando, y el codigo guardado en b (soup) no es el correspondiente al de la pagina que he indicado en consulta. si no uno diferente, por eso no se encuntra la etiqueta "null".

Sabeis porque no analiza el codigo de la pagina que yo especifico en consulta si no otro. Sabeis algun otro modo de hacerlo o veis algun fallo.

Muchas gracias.

**Código**:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    
    sitio="www.cloudflare.com"
    agent= {"User-Agent":"Firefox"}
    consulta= requests.get("https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host={}&t=1".format(sitio),headers=agent)
    b = BeautifulSoup(consulta.text,"html5lib") 
    c = b.find(id="null")
    d =c.find(border="1")
    for l in d.find_all("tr"):
        print("Sitio encontrado: " + l.td.string)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Comment: No pongas imagenes del código; pon el código mismo. Es la única manera de mirarlo, estudiarlo y analizarlo. Please.

Comment: perdona soy nuevo en la pagina, ya edite la publicacion y puse el codigo.  Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se trata de extraer una tabla hay una forma más sencilla usando pandas. Es más eficiente y menos código.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd #Llamas a pandas

sitio="www.cloudflare.com"
agent= {"User-Agent":"Firefox"}
consulta= requests.get("https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host={}&t=1".format(sitio),headers=agent)
df_list = pd.read_html(consulta.text) #Capturará todas las tablas que vea en tu html
print(df_list[3]) #El [3] es porque encontró varias tablas y la 3 es la que tiene lo que te interesa
```

Resultado:

```
                          0                   1
0                    Domain  Last Resolved Date
1                  2zyb.com          2020-06-23
2                   bl6.top          2020-09-16
3            cloudflare.com          2020-09-17
4   cloudnotificacion.email          2020-07-18
5                  ehraz.co          2020-09-12
6   image-contenthoster.com          2020-09-03
7        julianhackstein.de          2020-05-07
8                 levios.de          2020-09-10
9                  mgdw.org          2020-09-12
10           opcionauto.com          2020-09-03
11            star-night.tk          2020-09-12
12             starnight.tk          2020-09-12
13             undelice.com          2020-03-19
14       wedding-foreign.tk          2020-08-08
15               weiman.xyz          2020-06-30
16                 xhtk.xyz          2020-03-12
17          zhangyebing.com          2020-06-10
```

Al final si lo deseas puedes pasar tu tabla a list con `tolist()`

```
df_list = df_list[3].values.tolist()
```

Resultado:

```
[['Domain', 'Last Resolved Date'], ['2zyb.com', '2020-06-23'], ['bl6.top', '2020-09-16'], ['cloudflare.com', '2020-09-17'], ['cloudnotificacion.email', '2020-07-18'], ['ehraz.co', '2020-09-12'], ['image-contenthoster.com', '2020-09-03'], ['julianhackstein.de', '2020-05-07'], ['levios.de', '2020-09-10'], ['mgdw.org', '2020-09-12'], ['opcionauto.com', '2020-09-03'], ['star-night.tk', '2020-09-12'], ['starnight.tk', '2020-09-12'], ['undelice.com', '2020-03-19'], ['wedding-foreign.tk', '2020-08-08'], ['weiman.xyz', '2020-06-30'], ['xhtk.xyz', '2020-03-12'], ['zhangyebing.com', '2020-06-10']]
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113149/discussion-on-answer-by-alberto-castillo-imprimir-contenido-etiquetas-html).

Comment: Buena respuesta: +1

Answer (score 0):

este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd #Llamas a pandas

sitio="www.cloudflare.com"
agent= {"User-Agent":"Firefox"}
consulta= requests.get("https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host={}&t=1".format(sitio),headers=agent)
df_list = pd.read_html(consulta.text) #Capturará todas las tablas que vea en tu html
#print(df_list[3]) #El [3] es porque encontró varias tablas y la 3 es la que tiene lo que te interesa
```